# How to start a task wait for it while doing other work in the loop

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have an API call which accepts a batch of 100 rows of data per call, also it returns a sequence token, and that sequence token is important for the next call to be successful. But as the 100 rows are getting sent I want to be able to create the next batch of 100 rows, so that as soon as the previous API call is successful, I set the sequence token in the upcoming batch and send it.

I am not sure how to achieve it. I think I need to start a task and then await it later. Below is my attempt, please guide me.

```
// Alot of code removed for brevity sake, ignore logical errors.
string token = null;
public static async Task Send<TLog>(IEnumerable<TLog> logs)
{
    foreach (var log in logs)
    {

        if (logBatch.Count != 100)
            logBatch.Add(log);
        else
        {
            var response = await Put(logBatch, token); 
            token = response.NextSequenceToken; // set the sequence token for the next call
            logBatch.Clear();
            logBatch.Add(log);
        }
    }
}

public static async Task<PutLogEventsResponse> Put(List<InputLogEvent> logBatch, string token)
{
    PutLogEventsRequest req = new PutLogEventsRequest
    {
        LogEvents = logBatch,
        SequenceToken = token
    };

    return await logClient.PutLogEventsAsync(req); 
}
```

Comment: [Dataflow (Task Parallel Library)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library)

Comment: "But as the 100 rows are getting sent I want to be able to create the next batch of 100 rows" - is this possible since you have to wait for the logBatch list to be processed before clearing it and adding the next log ? Given that, you may want to consider Task.ContinueWith

Comment: @auburg - Once the api call has been made “PutLogEventsAsync” then I can change the batch.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially what you need to do is:

1. Create a batch of logs
2. Await the `Put` task that is currently processing from the previous batch (this will be empty on the first pass)
3. Start a new `Put` task in the background with the new batch of logs
4. Repeat

---

This would look something like:

```
Task<PutLogEventsResponse> currentPutTask = Task.FromResult<PutLogEventsResponse>(new PutLogEventsResponse { NextSequenceToken = null });
foreach (var log in logs)
{
    if (logBatch.Count != 100)
        logBatch.Add(log);
    else
    {
        token = (await currentPutTask).NextSequenceToken; // set the sequence token for the next call
        var currentBatchToProcess = new List<TLog>(logBatch);
        currentPutTask = Put(currentBatchToProcess , token);
        logBatch.Clear();
        logBatch.Add(log);
    }
}

// This line is needed so that the final batch is awaited
token = (await currentPutTask).NextSequenceToken;
```

---

Note that when you call `Put`, you'll need to pass in a new instance of a collection to avoid the collection from being modified while it's being used.